# How can I improve my export from Excel selection to text file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export Excel data to individual text files. Currently, the code I've got below exports the selection in Excel to a file titled "AgreementText.txt". I'd like to do two things to improve it, but I'm not sure how:

Firstly, I want to title each .txt file something different. The titles of the files are listed in a column 4 spaces to the left of each selection. Is there any way I can grab the title each time from that column?

Secondly, the text currently appears in the text file with quotation marks around it. Is there any way I can remove those?

Edit: Thirdly, I also need to specify a different file path to the default, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub TextFileExport()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\AgreementText.txt"
Set rng = Selection
Open myFile For Output As #1
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
    Write #1, cellValue
Else
    Write #1, cellValue,
End If
 Next j
Next i
Close #1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the title can easily just get retrieved by getting the cell value. Assuming it will be in the same row as the top of your selection, but 4 columns to the right, you can do it as follows:

```
myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & Selection.Cells(1, Selection.Columns.Count + 4) & ".txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
```

Secondly, you can use `Print` instead of `Write` to print without quotes. I find the easiest is to just build the whole line you want to write as one string and then do a single `Print` command for each line.

Putting it all together:

```
Sub TextFileExport()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim line
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Set rng = Selection
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & rng.Cells(1, rng.Columns.Count + 4) & ".txt"
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        line = ""
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            line = line & rng.Cells(i, j).Value
            If j < rng.Columns.Count Then
                line = line & ","
            End If
        Next
        Print #1, line
    Next
    Close #1
End Sub
```